# Make text invisible in contenteditable

Tags: html, css

I have a contenteditable span (display set to `inline-block`, so it doesn't act like a span, *per se*). I want the span to act like a password field on a linux terminal; you're typing, but you can't actually *see* it.

I've tried `visibility: hidden` and `display: none`, but both break the formatting and the text is still visible. Setting the color to the same as the background (black) makes the text invisible, but the caret is too.

I'd prefer for this to be done with CSS, but if it can't be done, I'll just use JavaScript. Here's my code:

```css
.input {
    display: inline;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

#field-in {
    color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <span id="field"><span id="field-name">Invisible Text:</span><span id="field-in" contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the caret color so that the caret is shown:

```css
.input {
    display: inline;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#field-in {
    color: #000000;
    caret-color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
#field-in::selection, #field-in::-moz-selection {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <span id="field"><span id="field-name">Invisible Text:</span><span id="field-in" contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: With `color` and `caret-color` switched, this would work well.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms If you switched those, you would make the caret invisible and the text visible. Is that what you wanted? If so, then I will accept your edit

Comment: Oh, the background is black. I guess I forgot to mention that, but it doesn't really change the integrity of the answer.

Comment: Ok, please add that to your post

Comment: The problem with this is that the text will still be shown if you mark it (for example pressing Ctrl+A). Other than that I would have had the exactly same approach.

Comment: @DigitalJedi I'll add that to my post

Comment: @DigitalJedi Couldn't something like `#field-in::selection` be used for that?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I added that to the post

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms If you set color to your background color then you could not see the text - you are right ;) , butt still, when inspecting the element I could still see the "hidden" text inside the html. I dont know if this is relevant for the user or not, i just wanted to point it out

Comment: @DigitalJedi You will never be able to hide anything on the client side. Inspecting the element could give you the contents even if it was set to `display: none`.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yes i know. well he/she wants it "to act like a password field". I dont know if he/she also wants it to be save or not. Im aware that if it really should be a password field this is definitely the wrong approach ^^

Comment: @DigitalJedi One could see the contents of a `<input type="password"/>` too...there is **no way** to hide anything on the client side from someone on the client side. And anyway, that's just hiding the information from the user himself/herself, or potentially someone looking over their shoulder. If I wanted to see what was in a password field, I could just do `document.getElementById("password-input-thing").value`, just like any other input type.

Answer (score 1):

Two CSS properties:

1. `color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`
2. `caret-color: red;`

One CSS pseudo-element:

1. `::-moz-selection { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }

   ::selection { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }`

The caret needs a contrasting color so adjust accordingly with `caret-color`. The value `rgba(0,0,0,0)` is transparent black -- the fourth 0 is alpha (opacity). The selection highlight is the same color so if the user selects the text with the default color (blue in Chrome) the text would be not be revealed. Note, this will work with any color background.

```css
.input {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background-color: none;
}

#field-in {
  outline: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  caret-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#field-in::-moz-selection {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#field-in::selection {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <span id="field"><span id="field-name">Invisible Text:</span><span id="field-in" contenteditable>Test</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's similar enough that I accepted the first.